# Cypress contains and cy.wait()

Tags: testing, cypress

I've got some problem with Cypress and wait command:
I am using similar to this code:

```
 const counter = cy.get('something')
        counter.contains('0') //OK
        const container = cy.xpath('something multiple').children()
        container.click({multiple:true})
        //cy.wait(200)
       counter.contains('3') //NOK
```

Only when I am using `cy.wait()` this code works. I've tried to use the internaltimeout for this code and
it's not working. Only works when using cy.wait.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to save Elements in variables, please use Alise instead.

```
   cy.get('something').as('counter');
   cy.get('@counter') .....
```

Read the documentation for your reference: 
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html

Comment: I think you have a typo alise -> alias?

Answer (score 0):

@HatemHatamleh is correct about not using the return value.

With `cy.*()` commands you are defining command execution steps, which will run separately from the JS in the tests.

Inserting `cy.wait()` kind-of works because it allows time for the commands to execute, but it's not at all the correct thing to do as it can fail depending on cpu load, async calls, etc.

Think of commands as a separate "thread", try to define them with chaining, but when that's not possible use alias' as @HatemHatamleh suggests.